# How to let user decide which service to request in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, communication

In WCF how to let user decide which service to request when you ask for two values and have ability to perform different calculations with those values.

For example you ask for value1 and value 2. And user have a choice to perform addition, subtraction and multiplication with those values.

How can you achieve that?

```
        [OperationContract]
    int GetTwoValues(int value1, int value2);

public int addition(int value1, int value2){
return value1+value2;
}

public int subtraction(int value1, int value2){
return value1-value2;
}
```

How to do some logic like

```
if user.request="addition"{
do addition
}
else if user.request="subtraction"{
do subtraction
}
```

i know its not a code that i have written but just trying to have you get some understanding of what i am saying. Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand the question

```
[OperationContract]
public int Subtraction(int value1, int value2)
{
    return value1 - value2;
}

[OperationContract]
public int Addition(int value1, int value2)
{
    return value1 + value2;
}
```

would work as would something like

```
[OperationContract]
public int Calculation(int value1, int value2, string calcType)
{
    switch (calcType)
    {
        case "addition":
            return value1 + value2;
        case "subtraction":
            return value1 - value2;
    }
    //return default or throw exception
}
```

Not that either is without drawbacks of course, but both meet your criteria.

edit: your comment raises the obvious point that the switch case allows the user to possibly supply a value that doesn't map.

Yes it does and I wouldn't use strings, that was your example!

Possible ways round it?

- Validate the user input - let them know when they provide something that isn't valid
- Use a default
- Throw an exception
- Use an `enum` to force the user to select from a pre defined list
- Similarly use the first method

I think perhaps you need to explain more in your question about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer its a bit near the solution but when i execute it creates one problem since nothing has been returned from the procedure.

Comment: Using which method? What input values? This is to give you an idea, implementation details depend on your real problem

Comment: using the same switch case method when you call for calType is it possible populated the list to the user to choose wht type of calculation to perform and do the chosen calculation?